# class java.math.BigInteger cannot be cast to class java.lang.Boolean

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, biginteger

I am trying to check whether the room name in that building exists or not.If exists, then don't save else save the data into the table.So I have written this query.

```
 @Query(value = "select exists(select name,building from meetingroom " +
            "where building=?1 and name=?2)",nativeQuery = true)
Boolean existsByRoom(String building,String name);
```

Now it is showing BigInteger cannot be cast to class java.lang.Boolean
Is there any way to solve this without effecting or changing the query.

Comment: Just change the Boolean return type to BigInteger?

Comment: @Reg The query returns 1 if exists and 0 if not exists
how to check that in the service layer?
if (meetingRoomRepository.existsByRoom(meetingRoomRequest.getBuilding(),meetingRoomRequest.getName()=""))


after getting the details what should i need to do later?? in the quotes place??

Comment: You can change query to 
select case when count(e)> 0 then true else false end from meetingroom where building=?1 and name=?2

Comment: @EgorPodoliak After changing my query to this query , I have to use boolean only right sir?

Comment: @EgorPodoliak I tried using that but it is showing that biginteger error only
how to use biginteger in service layer ??

if (meetingRoomRepository.existsByRoom(meetingRoomRequest.getBuilding(),meetingRoomRequest.getName()="")) 


like what should we put in the place of quotes??

Comment: Is there a reason to use native query instead of Spring's named query?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is here is to use JPA derived query.
Assuming your entity is MeetingRoom

```
Boolean existsMeetingRoomByBuildingAndName(String building, String name);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `java.util.Optional` like below. And you need to use BigInteger instead of Boolean because query will return BigInteger value when record exist.

```
    @Query(value = "select exists(select name,building from meetingroom " +
                    "where building=?1 and name=?2)",nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<BigInteger> existsByRoom(String building,String name);
```

And in service layer, you can check if the value is present.

```
    Optional<BigInteger> result = 
meetingRoomRepository.existsByRoom(meetingRoomRequest.getBuilding(),meetingRoomRequest.getName());
    if(result.isPresent()){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
```